# Fusion Tables SQL - Not Like

Tags: sql, google-fusion-tables

I am a little stuck. I know in normal SQL syntax, you can use `NOT LIKE 'x%'` to filter anything out that starts with an x.

I am trying to use an HTML SQL code for Fusion Tables, but my `NOT LIKE` is not working.

I think Fusion Tables does not support `NOT LIKE`. Any work around to achieve what I want?

I want to display data that does not contain the word 'Development'.

My code is:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?alt=csv&sql=SELECT * FROM My Fusion Table WHERE 'Task Name' IN 'Centre Visits' AND 'Expenditure Organization' NOT LIKE '%25Development%25' &key=KEY
```

Answer (score 0):

Is 'Task Name' your column?  Presuming that and 'Expenditure Organization' are both column names you would want something like this I'm guessing:

```
SELECT * FROM My Fusion Table 
WHERE [Task Name] IN 'Centre Visits' 
AND [Expenditure Organization] NOT LIKE '%25Development%25'
```

Note: your like wildcard is asking for a string not containing '25Development' and then another wild card and then the string ending again with '25'.  Perhaps double check to make sure that is what you want.